# Removing duplicated rows data frame in R

Tags: r

How can I remove duplicate rows from this example data frame?

```
A   1
A   1
A   2
B   4  
B   1
B   1
C   2
C   2
```

I would like to remove the duplicates based on both the columns:

```
A   1
A   2
B   4
B   1
C   2
```

Order is not important.

Comment: @whuber shouldn't that be moved to SO?

Comment: @Llopis Yes, but it's too late to do that now--and it was too late when we originally closed it.  This kind of question was considered (borderline) on-topic many years ago but nowadays it would be migrated quickly.

Answer (score 115, accepted):

`unique()` indeed answers your question, but another related and interesting function to achieve the same end is `duplicated()`.

It gives you the possibility to look up which rows are duplicated.

```
a <- c(rep("A", 3), rep("B", 3), rep("C",2))
b <- c(1,1,2,4,1,1,2,2)
df <-data.frame(a,b)

duplicated(df)
[1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE

> df[duplicated(df), ]
  a b
2 A 1
6 B 1
8 C 2

> df[!duplicated(df), ]
  a b
1 A 1
3 A 2
4 B 4
5 B 1
7 C 2
```

Comment: Thanks for mentioning the 'duplicated' function. It can be used to delete duplicated rows based on a subset of the columns.

Answer (score 51):

You are looking for `unique()`.

```
a <- c(rep("A", 3), rep("B", 3), rep("C",2))
b <- c(1,1,2,4,1,1,2,2)
df <-data.frame(a,b)
unique(df)

> unique(df)
  a b
1 A 1
3 A 2
4 B 4
5 B 1
7 C 2
```

Comment: Thanks Bernd. I thought unique can be applied only for a specific column. I didn't know that it can be used for the entire data frame as well. thanks again